# Dygraphs in R does not show color when viewing in browser

Tags: javascript, r, graphics, dygraphs

I am using "dygraphs" package in R to draw a bar chart and assign green color to all bars. The thing is totally fine when I display the chart in R, but all bars turn black when I try to display them in a web browser. Here is the code (a clip of Javascript is included because Google says I can use that to draw bar charts using dygraph):

```
library(xts)
library(dygraphs)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df  <- data.frame(date = as.Date(13800:13810, origin = "1970-01-01"),
                  n    = 1:11)

graph_data <- xts(x = 1:10, order.by = as.Date(13801:13810, origin = "1970-01-01"))

dygraph(graph_data) %>%
    dyOptions(useDataTimezone = TRUE,
              colors = c("008000"),
              plotter = 
                  "function barChartPlotter(e) {
            var ctx = e.drawingContext;
            var points = e.points;
            var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(0);  

            var bar_width = 1/2 * (points[1].canvasx - points[0].canvasx);
            ctx.fillStyle = e.color;

            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            var p = points[i];
            var center_x = p.canvasx;  // center of the bar

            ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
            bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
            ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
            bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
            }
            }")
```

I might have to use dygraphs to draw bars because it is fast in drawing thousands of bars...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How are you displaying the plot in the browser ?

Comment: Usually two cases. If I use Shiny in R instead of RStudio, the output is an HTML file and that is shown in a browser. In this case the dygraphs color is wrong, but the window created by RStudio is totally fine in terms of colors. Another case is that when I draw a dygraphs in RStudio, there is always an option at the "viewer" and you can show the output in the browser by clicking the second-to-the-rightest button. I am not exactly sure how to use Javascript to show dygraphs in a browser, but I think there is a way to put the graph in an HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing `'#'` while you are setting the color. Check the 
`colors = c("008000")` line. It should be `colors = c("#008000")`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I just tried that, but the problem still exists. Probably somewhere else is (also) broken...

Comment: That is working in my machine perfectly! I am using the code you have posted above with my suggested change (just inserting #).